# Jensen inequality for concave functions

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

Suppose $f(x)=\sqrt x$. From Jensen Inequality, we know that $f(x_1)+f(x_2)-2f((x_1+x_2)/2)\leq0$. I am trying to show that if $x_3>x_1$, $x_3>x_2$, $x_4>x_1$ and $x_4>x_2$, then 
$$
f(x_1)+f(x_2)-2f((x_1+x_2)/2)-(f(x_3)+f(x_4)-2f((x_3+x_4)/2))\ge 0.
$$ 
with $x_i=i{a}^{i-1}- \left( i-1 \right) {a}^{i-2}+b$, a>1 and b>=1. Anybody can help?

Comment: I assume $x \geq 0$. You have a definition of $f(x)$ and by the inequalities given, $f(x_3) > f(x_1)$, $f(x_4) > f(x_1)$, etc. So, what happens when you plug in the givens into your inequality?

Comment: It seems to me that the inequality is false without some further conditions on the $x_i$'s. I would guess the other inequality holds if for example you fix the difference $x_2-x_1=x_4-x_3$

Comment: The difference is not fixed and $x_i$'s are larger than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps
$$
f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)=h^2f''(\tilde x)
$$
with $\tilde x\in (x-h,x+h)$ can help?

---

It tells you that your expression is 
$$
-\frac1{16}\frac{(x_2-x_1)^2}{\sqrt{x_{12}}^{\,3}}+\frac1{16}\frac{(x_4-x_3)^2}{\sqrt{x_{34}}^{\,3}}\overset{?}{\ge}0
$$ 
with $x_{12}$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$, $x_{34}$ between $x_3$ and $x_4$. It is now easy to devise counter examples where the difference $|x_4-x_3|$ is relatively small or zero.

Even when $|x_4-x_3|=|x_2-x_1|$, you get because of $$x_{34}\ge\min(x_3,x_4)>\max(x_1,x_2)\ge x_{12}$$ that the expression has a negative value.

---

The desired inequality is certainly satisfied for $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$ if
$$
\frac{(x_4-x_3)^2}{(x_2-x_1)^2}\ge\frac{x_4^{3/2}}{x_1^{3/2}}
$$
as $\frac{x_4}{x_1}$ is the maximum of the possible values of the fraction of the midpoints $\frac{x_{34}}{x_{12}}$.

Comment: not really, because the difference between terms is not fixed.

Comment: @Bright : It tells you how to simplify your inequality and find counter examples.

Comment: @Bright : If it was not clear, $x_1,\frac{x_1+x_2}2,x_2$ and $x_3,\frac{x_3+x_4}2,x_4$ are equally spaced triples.

Comment: @Bright $(x_1,x_2)=(1,2)$ and $(x_3,x_4)=(3,4)$ is a counterexample

Comment: @Del True in your example, in my case $x_i=i{a}^{i-1}- \left( i-1 \right) {a}^{i-2}+b$. Both a and b are larger than 1.

Comment: Try to graph it, in `gnuplot` the sequence of commands `a=4; b=10; f(x) = x*a**(x-1)+(x-1)*a**(x-2)+b; plot [1:20] sqrt(f(x))+sqrt(f(x+1))-2*sqrt((f(x)+f(x+1))/2)` gives a strictly falling graph.

Comment: @LutzL if I understand you correctly, you are saying to plot f(x) to see it is decreasing and perhaps smaller than 0? But Jensen's inequality already says that f(x)<=0.

Comment: sorry, bad choice of function name. gnuplot reserves the variables `x,y` (and `z,t`). Your $x_i$ is computed with `f(i)`. What is plotted is the linear combination of the square roots. So you have to do some careful translation between problem variable names and gnuplot variables. For integer `x` (`x`$=i$, `f(x)`$=x_i$) the plotted expression is $\sqrt{x_i}+\sqrt{x_{i+1}}+2\sqrt{(x_i+x_{i+1})/2}$ and the falling graph shows that the expression gets smaller for larger $i$, at least in the example with $a=4$ and $b=10$ (and also for $a=2$ and $b=1$).

Comment: This is exactly what I want to show that the expression gets smaller for larger i but how?

Comment: Yeah, I just came to the same conclusion that you want larger negative values, not falling absolute values as I was basing, erroneously, my comments on. It will be a mess unless one finds simplified and weakened conditions in the general case $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$. I still think the second derivatives can help, the inequality is satisfied if $$\frac{(x_4-x_3)^2}{(x_2-x_1)^2}\ge\frac{x_4^{3/2}}{x_1^{3/2}}$$. One probably could take some closer fraction on the right, as these are the extremal positions of the midpoints, but in general the midpoint will be close to the middle of the interval.

Comment: @Lutzl, does the equality you mentioned above has a specific name?

Comment: Not that I know of, it is just a form of expressing that the second difference quotient approximates the second derivative. It can be obtained by twice applying the mean value theorem: $$\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}=\frac{f'(x+h_1)-f(x-h_1)}{2h_1}=f''(\tilde x)$$ with $0<h_1<h$ and $\tilde x\in(x-h_1,x+h_1)$.